# Error occur when Testing a testcase using NUnit Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, selenium-firefoxdriver, nunittestadapter

```
class NunitTest
{

 IWebDriver driver;



[SetUp]
public void Initialize()

{

driver = new FirefoxDriver();

}

[Test]
public void openAppTest()

{

driver.Url ="http://www.demoqa.com";

}

[TearDown]
public void EndTest()

{

driver.Close();

}

}
```

I wrote a simple testcase, but when I try to Run Test using Visual Studio 2017, it shows this error message of Test discovery was cancelled after 30 s for executable. Can anyone help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code example:

```
namespace Testing
{

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework.Constraints;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Core.Extensions;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using Syncfusion.UnitTesting.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Collections;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Drawing;
using SanityTesting.AccordionFluent;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[TestFixture("Firefox")]
public class TestClass : NUnitUtil
{
    string activeBrowser;

    public TestClass(string browser)
    {

        FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Drivers");
        service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";          
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
        activeBrowser = browser;           
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void quitDriver()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }



    [Test)]
    [Category("Sanity")]
    public void Test1(string url, int time)
    {
         //your test code//
    }
}
```

I think You are missing setup of driver.

try this example, hope it helps,

Comment: may i know for this session [TestDirectory("..\\..\\Accordion\\")] what TestDirectory i need to put in?

Comment: ignore that, c/p error. just use service for setting up.